# Check if NSURL returns 404

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I need to check whether a URL (represented by a NSURL) is available or returns 404. What is the best way to achieve that?

I would prefer a way to check this without a delegate, if possible. I need to block the program execution until I know if the URL is reachable or not.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As you may know already that general error can capture by didFailWithError method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]);
}
```

but for 404 "Not Found" or 500 "Internal Server Error" should able to capture inside didReceiveResponse method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(statusCode)])
    {
        int statusCode = [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode];
        if (statusCode == 404)
        {
            [connection cancel];  // stop connecting; no more delegate messages
            NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse statusCode with %i", statusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that there's a handy class method on NSHTTPURLResponse to return a localized description for the error code: `[NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode: [response statusCode]]`

Comment: Is it possible to have this in Swift..? Thank you very much

Comment: I'm sure you do this in Swift version. Convert by hand would not be difficult.

Comment: @Jirapong: I have few doubts. Which kind of errors are captured in connection: didReceiveResponse: and which are in connection: didFailWithError: ?

Comment: @rashmi-ranjan-mallick didFailWithError is the connection cannot connect to server. didReceiveResponse is the connection able to connect but there is status along with it as standard HTTP Status Code.

Comment: Ok!! So, to effectively handle all the errors, I will have to handle it in both delegate methods (connection: didReceiveResponse: and connection: didFailWithError:). Am I correct?  My doubt is, in case connection: didReceiveResponse: gets called with a error HTTP status code, will it also call connection: didReceiveData: or connection: didFinishLoading: after that? How should I retrieve the error message from response object?

Answer (score 29):

I needed a solution that didn't use a delegate either, so I took pieces of code shown in other answers here and created a simple method that works well in my case (and might be what you are looking for as well):

```
    -(BOOL) webFileExists {

        NSString *url = @"http://www.apple.com/somefile.html";

        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:5.0];
        NSHTTPURLResponse* response = nil;
        NSError* error = nil;
        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSLog(@"statusCode = %d", [response statusCode]);

        if ([response statusCode] == 404)
            return NO;
        else
            return YES;
     }
```

Comment: That is not very useful on big files. It will download the entire file before returning a response

Comment: This works great, thanks. For others looking to do this, you might consider checking for a `200` status code so you know your file is accessible since any number of errors could occur besides a `404` such as `403 Forbidden` and `500 Internal Server Error`. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I used the answer from woodmantech above, but changed it based on what I have seen on other similar questions here so that it does not download the whole file to see if it exists.

I changed `NSURLRequest` to `NSMutableURLRequest`, and added:

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
```

This seems to work fine. I am working on my first app, so no real experience yet. Thanks everyone.

```
 NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:5.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
    NSHTTPURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"statusCode = %d", [response statusCode]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve a synchronous connection by calling:

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSHTTPURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Your thread will block until the request has beeen made.

Comment: Synchronous requests block the GUI and also waste resources. Asynchronous does not and allows on top of that better error handling and canceling.

Comment: Nope, that's wrong. If nothing is at `url`, it won't block : NSURLConnection will download the content of the 404 webpage. But you can check the status code with `[response statusCode]`

Comment: @MacMark Why do you assume a synchronous request will block the GUI?  What if I've very carefully placed it in an NSOperation that won't?  At which point -- to get to my question -- how exactly do they 'waste resources' compared to an asynchronous request?  (For that matter, how do they allow for better error handling...  unless you use the NSURlConnection protocol instead, which I think you can still do if you really want to, though it's a bit more complicated and if you've already threaded the operation, is completely counterproductive and a waste of resources itself!)