# How to check if a file exists at particular URL?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

How do I check if a file exists on a web site?  I am using `NSURLConnection` with my `NSURLRequest` and an `NSMutableData` object to store what comes back in the `didReceiveData:` delegate method.  In the `connectionDidFinishingLoading:` method I then save the `NSMutableData` object to the file system.  All good.  Except: if the file does not exist at the website, my code still runs, gets data and saves a file.

How can I check the file is there before I make download request?

Comment: That's why there exists a `HEAD` verb in HTTP, instead of making a `GET` request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `connection:didReceiveResponse:`, which will be called before `connection:didReceiveData:`.

The response should be an `NSHTTPURLResponse` object — suppose you're issuing an HTTP request. You can therefore check `[response statusCode] == 404` to determine if the file exists or not.

See also [Check if NSURL returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404366/check-if-nsurl-returns-404).

Comment: That is great thanks Kenny.  Do you know if I can/should implement the following in my didReceiveResponse?

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 404) // File does not exist
    {
        [connection cancel];
    }

Comment: Sorry should have added, that all works a treat.  Just wondering if it is recommended to cancel the connection like that?

Comment: This does not work. It gives a false positive - incorrectly indicating the existence of a file when there is none.

Answer (score 3):

1.File in your bundle

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image"    ofType:@"png"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
if (fileExists) {
NSLog(@"file exists");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"file not exists");
}
```

2.File in your directory

```
NSString* path =  [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
if (fileExists) {
NSLog(@"file exists");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"file not exists");
}
```

3.File in web

```
NSString *urlString=@"http://eraser2.heidi.ie/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack-pro/images/default-user-image.png";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
NSLog(@"%@",response);
[connection cancel];
NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
int code = (int)[httpResponse statusCode];
if (code == 200) {
    NSLog(@"File exists");
}
else if(code == 404)
{
    NSLog(@"File not exist");
}
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"File not exist");
}
```