# How to know image present at the url

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I have url for image picked using `ELCImagePickerController`. I stored the url for future reference.

I get that URL using:

```
[dict valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

Now the problem arises when after some time user deleted that particular image from photo library
and I am going to access that image using URL.
My app does not get crashed.

I have tried using NSUrl method

```
[imagePath checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err]
```

as well i tried something like:

```
-(BOOL)findImage:(NSURL*)path
{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    __block BOOL flag=YES;
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];
        if (iref) {
            flag=YES;
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }
    };
    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        NSLog(@"cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
        flag=NO;
    };
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:path resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(group);
    [assetslibrary release];

    return flag;
}
```

Sample url :

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=E862927E-E646-448A-9EB6-A7D48668B3DC&ext=JPG
```

But no success.

How to know that image present at particular URL.

If any one can help me out on this will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008399/objective-c-checking-if-url-exists

check this it might help you

Comment: @PrakashDesai I gone through your provided link. I need to check file exist in photo library of iphone/ipad or not.

Comment: Try [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath]

Comment: @Alex I tried it before and again now but no success.

Comment: Can you add a path(url) of the image to your question, it might help us.

Comment: added sample URL please have a look at edit.

Comment: Did you manage to load(access) the image?

Comment: @Alex Yes I do access the image

Comment: so if you do access the image you can try to load it to UIImage object. If result is not nil -> image exists.

Comment: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourNSURL]];

Comment: @Alex I have thought of that before but the problem is that, I have several number of urls so creating so many objects may not feasible, so i want different solution. Sometimes number of urls can goes beyond 100.

Comment: if you use ARC the UIImage instance should be released automatically after you've done your check.

Comment: @Alex my project is not ARC enabled. And I have to use it in non ARC mode. I tried but it gives saveral memory warnings on device. tried with instruments as well it shows nothing leaked. so want different solution.

Comment: you can manually release the image after checking if you not using ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem with change in the **findImage** method

```
-(BOOL)findImage:(NSURL*)path
{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    __block BOOL flag=YES;
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:path resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        if (asset==nil)
        {
            flag=NO;
        }
        else
        {
            flag=YES;
        }
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
                NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!");
                dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(group);
    [assetslibrary release];
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case you need to check ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation] to nil.

`if(rep != nil){
    //write your code..
}`