# How to use NSURLSession to determine if a redirected link is broken?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to use `NSURLSession` to determine if a link is broken after passing in an array of URLs.  The problem with the below code is that myURL in the line `else { print("no data back from getDataFromSErverWithSuccess and this is the problem: \(myURL)")}` returns nil.  How can I get the value of the URL that is broken?

```
class MySession: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate {


    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {


        if let checkedURL = request.URL {

            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(checkedURL) {
                print("\(checkedURL) works")

            } else {
                print("\(checkedURL) IS BROKE!")
            }
        }


    }

    // fetch data from URL with NSURLSession
    class func getDataFromServerWithSuccess(myURL: String, noRedirect: Bool, success: (response: String!) -> Void) {
        var myDelegate: MySession? = nil
        if noRedirect {
            myDelegate = MySession()
        }
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: myDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)
        let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: myURL)!) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if let checkedData = data {

                success(response: NSString(data: checkedData, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as! String)
                } else { print("no data back from getDataFromSErverWithSuccess and this is the problem: \(myURL)")}
        }
        loadDataTask.resume()
    }
```

EDIT:  this is where I'm calling `getDataFromServerWithSuccess` can I get the url by adding an error block here?

```
MySession.getDataFromServerWithSuccess(urlAsString, noRedirect: false, success:
                                        { (response: String!) -> Void in

                                    })
```

Comment: canOpenURL Returns a Boolean value indicating whether or not the URL’s scheme can be handled by some app installed on the device not if the URL is broken. see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:      If you want to check if a URL is online you need to check the returned HTTPURLResponse status code. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008399/objective-c-checking-if-url-exists

Comment: Thanks ```canOpenURL``` was just an initial check, the real testing of whether the URL was online is in the ```session.dataTashWithURL```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the redirected request with property `currentRequest` from the session task.

Source: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionTask/currentRequest)

Comment: Thank you! but how can I access that property here ```loadDataTask.currentRequest```  where it would be a variable used within it's own initial value?

Comment: @PSUSabes Make `loadDataTask` an Optional var and initialise it with `nil`. Then you can access it in the completion closure.

Comment: ```loadDataTask.currentRequest``` returns the initial url, not the "source" url that the redirect ends up with

Comment: Perhaps, because the redirect URL failed?! You may now add the delegate method `URLSession(_:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)` in order to investigate the issue. The delegate will be called _before_ the redirect is performed. If it turns out that `currentRequest` is only setup if it _succeeded_ I would consider it a bug in NSULRSession.

Comment: I think the problem was I was passing in an optional, it was several levels of unwrapping so I didn't notice.  ```currentRequest.url``` is telling me the redirect's URL now...thanks for the help!