# How to check if UIImage loaded from a URL is valid

Tags: iphone

Is there a way I can check if there is valid image in the NSData I've loaded into my UIImage object?

The UIImage is loading in from NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]]];
```

Thanks

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this ? It would be helpful to the rest of us.

Comment: Check answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072613/how-to-check-if-a-nsdata-is-valid-for-usage-in-uiimage

Answer (score 2):

see here.
[Check if NSURL returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404366/check-if-nsurl-returns-404) 
using NSURLConnection you can get the statuscode

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by a valid image. If you do

`[UIImage imageNamed:]`

and the image isn't valid, it will return nil, so you can do:

`UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"]`

`if (myImage != nil) { ... }`

Comment: Sorry Mike I haven't made my question quite clear. I am initializing an image with a URLString. In my case sometimes there would be an image on remote site and sometimes not. I have read the data by converting it into string and it says in title '404 Not Found'. I have also tried using NSPredicate to see if return string contains '404 Not Found' in it so I can put in place proper validation but it is not working. I would really appreciate if someone could help me in right direction. Thanks